# C++ -- Why should we use operator -> to access member functions of a SmartPtr?

Tags: c++

The question is given in the last two lines of code.

```
template<class T>                    // template class for smart
class SmartPtr {                     // pointers-to-T objects
public:
  SmartPtr(T* realPtr = 0);

  T* operator->() const;
  T& operator*() const;

  T* Detach( void )
  {
    T* pData = pointee;
    pointee = NULL;
    return pData;
  }  

private:
  T *pointee;
  ...
};

class TestClass {}

SmartPtr<TestClass> sPtr(new TestClass);

TestClass* ptrA = sPtr->Detach();
// why I always see people use this method to access member functions of a Smart pointer.
// We can use sPtr-> b/c we have defined operator->() in SmartPtr.    

TestClass* ptrB = sPtr.Detach();  
// Question: Is this a valid C++ way? If not, why?
```

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SmartPtr<TestClass> sPtr(new TestClass);
TestClass* ptrA = sPtr->Detach();
```

Is actually invalid, because `TestClass` has no member function `Detach`. `operator->` of the `SmartPtr` class is declared as `T* operator->() const`, as such (should) return the `pointee` of the smart pointer.

```
TestClass* ptrB = sPtr.Detach();
```

Is the valid version, because `sPtr` itself is just a normal local stack variable, not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

They are both valid syntax, but call different functions!

p.detach() will call a detach function of the p object
p->detach() will call a detach function of the object p points to, of type T

Quite a difference!